# How to change the width and height of an image thats specified in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a div with the width of 50% and a height of 540px. I set the background-repeat to no-repeat but the problem is that the image is not covering the "image-placeholder"

I am open to suggestions about JQuery and Javascript.

```css
li {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}

a:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}

#topnavbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  border-bottom: 1px lightgray solid;
}

#logotext {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgb(24, 72, 150);
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

div#content:first-child {
  background-image: url(https://www.sitebuilderreport.com/assets/facebook-stock-up-446fff24fb11820517c520c4a5a4c032.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 540px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px black solid;
}

#content2 {
  background-image: url(https://www.stockvault.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/summer-stock-photos-320x216.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 540px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px black solid;
}

#content3 {
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/33045/lion-wild-africa-african.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 540px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px black solid;
}

#logo {
  width: 10%;
  margin-top: -34px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnavbar">
  <p id="logotext"><img id="logo" src="logo.png"></p>
  <ul id="ullist">
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<center>
  <div id="content"></div><br>
  <div id="content2"></div><br>
  <div id="content3"></div><br>
  <div id="content4"></div><br>
  <div id="content5"></div>
</center>
```

Comment: try adding  background-size: cover; to your div's css class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using Javascript you can use CSS property background-size set to value 'cover'.
It will re-scale the background image to be as large as to cover the whole container area. It will save the aspect ratio of the picture. Part of image can overflow outside of container - this is one cons of using this solution.

```
background-size: cover;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c59c1pja/

If you do NOT care about image aspect ratios you can use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

which will transform the image to dimensions of the container

https://jsfiddle.net/6bpddoym/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `cover` as @Lukasz mentioned, changing `background-repeat` to `round` can help with some of the stretching.

```
  /* snip */
  background-repeat: round;
  background-size: cover;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/5t3dsjna/15/